# multi step string split using php

Tags: php, custom-post-type

I have a Wordpress site that I am building for a client and one custom post type field will allow users to enter a link and then the text for the link in a format as pictured below and called resources.
[image]

That info them needs to be output in an anchor tag as a `<li>`. I am newish to php and this is what I have so far for code

```
<ul>
<?php
        $rawcontent = get_field("resources");
        $rawcontent = preg_replace("!</?p[^>]*>!", "", $rawcontent); 
        $all_links = preg_split("/(\n)/", $rawcontent);
        $firstpart = array_pop(explode(',', $rawcontent));

   foreach($all_links as $link) {
       if(!trim($link)) continue;
       echo "<li><a href='$link'>$firstpart</a></li>";
   }
?>
</ul>
```

when I print $rawcontent (resources) before any of my code executes is apperas as:
www.mylink1.com,link copy 1

www.mylink2.com, link copy 2

www.mylink3.com,link copy 3

with the code I have implemented now it comes out as 
[image]

How can I get this to return just the link for the href and the just the link copy part for the anchor text for each anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it.
I first explode on new line just like you do, then I foreach the lines.
When I foreach the lines I explode the line on comma.
Now I have an array with link as first item, and text as the second item.

```
$str = "www.mylink1.com,link copy 1
www.mylink2.com, link copy 2
www.mylink3.com,link copy 3";

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

Foreach($lines as $line){
    $linktext = explode(",", $line);
    Echo  "<li><a href='$linktext[0]'>$linktext[1]</a></li>";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/9DEoo

I see that your link2 has a space in the text.
You can remove that with trim when you echo.

```
Echo  "<li><a href='" . trim($linktext[0]) . "'>" . trim($linktext[1]) . "</a></li>\n";
```

I added trim on both link and text, it can be good to have. Just in case...
https://3v4l.org/6RkW3

Comment: Andreas thank you!! I was getting more and more confused as I tried to figure this out, your solution worked perfectly!!